# prove that if $\exists a\in A\space:\space stb(a)\not=\{e\}$ then the action is unfaithful

Tags: group-theory

let $G$ be abelian group which acts on non empty set $A$.

 prove that if $\exists a\in A\space:\space stb(a)\not=\{e\}$ then the action is unfaithful (the kernel of the action is not trivial).

**notation**: 
- $e$ is the identity
 - $stb(a)=\{g\in G\space :\space g\cdot a=a\}$ where $g\cdot a$ means that $g$ acts on $a$.

I manged to prove that for any element in some orbit the stabilizer is the same, yet could not proceed from there.

Comment: This claim is false. For example, $G$ can act faithfully on a subset of $A$, while fixing all elements in the complement.

Comment: I didn't really get the idea, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G$ acts transitively on $A$, for a moment, and let $g\neq e$ be in the stabilizer of $a\in A$.

For an arbitrary element $b\in A$, there exists $h\in G$ such that $b=h\cdot a$. Then $g\cdot b=g\cdot(h\cdot a)=h\cdot (g\cdot a)=h\cdot a=b$, so $g$ would also stabilize $b$. Thus $g$ stabilizes everything, and the action isn't faithful.

---

Now go back to the general situation and suppose that $G$ acts on $A$ such that $g\neq e$ stablizes $a\in A$. Form the new set $C$ which is the disjoint union of $A$ and $G$, and let $G$ act on $C$ in the obvious way (by acting on elements according to $A$'s action if they are from $A$, and according to $G$'s action on itself if they are from $G$).

Now, $g$ still stabilizes $a\in A$, but it can't stabilize $e\in G$, so the action is not unfaithful on $C$. This counterexample leads me to believe your question was intended to be for transitive actions only.

Comment: +1 for finding the logic behind the question. Note that there are other, much simpler counterexamples. For instance, take a faithful action on $A$, and add an element on which $G$ acts trivially.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval OK: replacing $A$ with a singleton is simpler, but *much* simpler might be an overstatement :)